# Does anyone know where the error is in this CSS code?

Tags: css, nested, html-lists, nav

I copied this code as an example of a nested ul and li inside a nav, but my vs code is showing me there is an error, can anyone point it out to me?

```
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not CSS. That's SASS or LESS

Comment: Do you want to convert it to CSS? Since this is not CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid CSS syntax, since CSS does not support nesting blocks like that. Your code is written in a [CSS preprocessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_preprocessor) syntax like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](https://lesscss.org/).

It is equivalent to this vanilla CSS code:

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Your editor is probably complaining because you included this inside a file with the .css extension. It needs to be saved as .scss or .less depending on flavor and then you need a compiler to turn it into vanilla CSS.